# Not able to Add more text in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add text in a `textarea`. I think I'm missing some ....my code is below:

```
$.each(result, function (i, v) {
  if (ui.item.value === v.TextKeyword) {
    if ($('input:radio[name="' + currentid + '"]:checked').val() == 'Append') {
      var cannedtext = $("textarea[parentcontrolid='" + currentid + "']").text() + "," + v.Text;
      $("textarea[parentcontrolid='" + currentid + "']").text(String(cannedtext));
    } else {
      $("textarea[parentcontrolid='" + currentid + "']").text(v.Text);
    }
    $("textarea[parentcontrolid='" + currentid + "']").focus();
  }
});
```

but when I execute the code it displays this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help if you indented your code properly.

Comment: @diy - Have you specified `maxLengh` attribute

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

According to [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

Comment: @diy Can you provide a  demo or post your completed code?

Comment: @diy Do you have teamviewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97009/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-diy).